# How to document Matlab project with multiple classes using sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain?

Tags: python, matlab, python-sphinx

I tried to document a larger Matlab project using Sphinx and the sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain package. It works fine for a single folder that stores all .m files. However my project contains multiple classes stored in separate folders such as:

```
   project
    |-- matfiles
    |    |-- @class1
    |    |    |-- class1.m
    |    |    |-- method1.m
    |    |    |-- method2.m
    |    |    +-- method1.m
    |    |-- @class2
    |    |    |-- class2.m
    |    |    |-- methodA.m
    |    |    |-- methodB.m
    |    |    +-- methodC.m
    |    +-- function
    |         |-- fun1.m
    |         |-- fun2.m
    |         +-- fun3.m
    +-- doc
         |-- conf.py
         +-- index.rst
```

I adde the following lines to `conf.py`:

```
matlab_src_dir = os.path.abspath('..')
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinxcontrib.matlab',
]
primary_domain = 'mat'
```

And I added the following lines to `index.rst`:

```
.. module:: matfiles

.. automethod:: class1.method1
```

I got the following error:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sphinxcontrib/mat_documenters.py", line 788, in import_object
    if self.object.attrs.get('Static'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
The full traceback has been saved in /var/folders/70/g0lr37wn60gbbymnsks_t5vm0000gn/T/sphinx-err-uD8qpe.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
| reading sources... [100%] index
```

So my question is, is there a way to document multi class Matlab projects where class methods are saved in a folder with name @class?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just found the [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359933). The `documentation` tag has been marked for burnination and general clean-up. My retagging is in accordance with established policy.

Comment: @bad_coder: thanks! It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue has been resolved in the latest version, [sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain-0.2.7](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain), which autodocuments class methods with attributes defined in separate files of a `@classfolders`. Let me know if it's still an issue.